# Accessing Multipule Arrays From JSON

Tags: arrays, json, attributes, element

I have some JSON withing an elements attribute and one of the JSON elements has a value of multiple arrays. I have worked out how to access the array if there is one but I'm not sure how to access the second one.

I could also do with knowing how to push a new array to the JSON value.

Here is What I have

```
    $(this).attr({
"data-settings": $.toJSON({ nPosX: newPX, nPosY: newPY, oPosX: oldPX, oPosY: oldPY, moves: ["val"]["key"] })
});

var movesObj = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-settings'));
```

The `moves` is where the arrays are kept.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: `moves: ["val"]["key"]` does not do what you probably think it does. It will try to access the `key` property of the `["val"]` array. This property does not exist, so it returns `undefined`. Hence, the result of this is `moves: undefined`. How exactly do you want `moves` to be structured? An array or arrays? An array with two elements?

Comment: If you do `movesObj.moves[0]` you can access the "val".
Preferably and array of arrays.

Comment: With that setup? I doubt it: http://jsfiddle.net/g7E7C/ In any ways, you definitely should read about [arrays in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object). And if you want `movesObj.moves[0]` to return `val`, then it seems want an array wit two elements: `moves: ["val", "key"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that does not seem like a valid JSON to me. You can't define a JSON like that. You either define moves like an hash:

```
moves: {"val":"key"}
```

you access it like: *moves.val* or *moves["val"]*

Or you define moves like an array of hashes:

```
moves: [{"val":"key"}, ...]
```

You access it like: *moves[0].val* or *moves[0]["val"]*.

If you want a nested hash like that, you need to define it like:

```
moves: {"val": {"key":"value"}}
```

And access it like *moves["val"]["key"]* or *moves.val.key*

Comment: I think the array of hashes is what I'm looking for, how would I push a new array of hashes in to moves?

Comment: For example `moves: [{ posX: nX, posY: nY, time: 0 }], [{ posX: nX, posY: nY, time: 3 }]`

How would I add that second array?

Comment: Never mind I'll use the answer I got here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492472/how-do-i-add-a-array-to-a-json-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492472/how-do-i-add-a-array-to-a-json-object)

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific about what you are trying to do?

If you have nested arrays and you want to access a value from one of the inner arrays, the syntax is

```
myArray["key1"]["key2"]
```

or

```
myArray.foo.bar
```

Comment: I'm trying to access "val" and "key" from the JSON element `moves`

Comment: Could you edit the question to include some idea of what the `moves` array is supposed to do? As Felix said above, `["key"]["val"]` is not what you want to do.