# How do I add a Array to a JSON object

Tags: arrays, json, push

I'm trying to record an objects movements with an attached attribute called `data-settings` so far I have managed to set up some sort of JSON/Array but I want one of the objects to hold multiple arrays of hashes like so.

`{ nPosX: newPX, nPosY: newPY, moves: [{ posX: newPX, posY: newPY, time: 0 }], [{ posX: newPX, posY: newPY, time: 5 }] }`

However I'm struggling to add another array to the `moves` so I only have this:

`{ nPosX: newPX, nPosY: newPY, moves: [{ posX: newPX, posY: newPY, time: 0 }] }`

How do I push an array with hashes to `moves`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
el = { nPosX: newPX, nPosY: newPY, moves: [{ posX: newPX, posY: newPY, time: 0 }] }
el.moves.push({ posX: newPX, posY: newPY, time: 5 })
```

Gives:

```
{ nPosX: newPX, nPosY: newPY, moves: [{ posX: newPX, posY: newPY, time: 0 },{ posX: newPX, posY: newPY, time: 5 }] }
```

Your original syntax isn't valid as you have two arrays containing a single object each attached to the "moves" key. It's not valid JSON.

See : http://www.json.org/

Comment: Thanks, sorry it may seem like a silly question but how do I access each set of data.

Comment: Depends on the language. Assuming JavaScript, parse JSON into "el" Object. Then use el.moves to access the "moves" array. And el.moves[0].posX to access the posX value inside the first "moves" element.

Answer (score 0):

No extra square brackets required. So:

```
moves: [
    { posX: newPX, posY: newPY, time: 0 },
    { posX: newPX, posY: newPY, time: 5 }
]
```